# Extend Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, child-theme

A theme I use registers a custom post-type. Unfortunately its supports array misses an item, I would like to add ('thumbnail'). Now, I don't like to overwrite the post-types registration in the theme and instead would like to "extend" it (via my child-theme). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`add_post_type_support`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support). A usage example from the Codex:

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');
function my_custom_init() {
    add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
```

Comment: It is better to hook into `registered_post_type` and check if the post type you want to change is really there. `init` might be too early, depending the registration details.